# Trying to convert int fields to string inside a inherited class

Tags: c#

I have a base class provided to me, with these fields:

```
public class OrdersModel
{
  public int orderType {get; set;}
  public int status {get; set;}
  public int accountType {get; set;}
}
```

I want to create a new class which can override these fields, each field will return a string, depending on the int value the database sends back. For example:

```
public class OrdersViewModel : OrdersModel
{
  public int orderType {
     get {
           case: (orderType == 0)
               return ("Standard Shipping");
               break;
           case: (orderType == 1)
               return ("Express Shipping");
               break;
           default:
               return ("Value Shipping");

         set{}    

         }
     }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get errors: *Code is unreacheable or cannot convert type string to return type int*

I could just turn these fields into strings in the base class, but the parent class is being used elsewhere. I just want the inherited class to display human readable values.

My question is the following: Is there a way I can cast or override the fields and make them return string instead of int?

thank you

Comment: Enums could also be useful here.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko why aren't breaks needed?

Comment: @Kirk because you're `return`ing so the `break` never gets reached.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *override* just by changing the return type, but you can *hide* a property:

```
public class OrdersViewModel : OrdersModel
{
    public new string orderType {
        get 
        {
            switch(((OrdersModel)this).orderType) 
            {
                case(0):
                    return ("Standard Shipping");
                case (1):
                    return ("Express Shipping");
                default:
                    return ("Value Shipping");
            }
        }
        set{ /* reverse mapping from string to int */ ;}    
    }
}
```

However *inheriting* a viewmodel from a Model is generally not the best option.  It may *seem* like you're reducing duplication, but tools like `AutoMapper` make it very easy to map from one class to another, and you don't pollute your model with validation logic or have to override/hide properties that you want *slightly* different in your viewmodel.  Consider either encapsulating or mapping.  I also prefer mapping because it decouples your viewmodel from a specific model implementation.

Comment: This won't compile. There's an errant `set`

Comment: I have never heard of this tool before. I guess I should check it out. Thanks for the help. The code didn't work per se (no more errors at least), but I learned a new concept today.

Comment: @KirkBrannigan Very handy for mapping between classes where most of the properties are the same name and type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**Change type to dynamic**

```
public class OrdersModel
{
    public  dynamic orderType { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int accountType { get; set; }
}
```

and then **Change type to dynamic here also**

```
public class OrdersViewModel : OrdersModel
{
    private int _OT;
    public  dynamic orderType
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this._OT)
            {
                case 0:
                    return ("Standard Shipping");

                case 1:
                    return ("Express Shipping");

                default:
                    return ("Value Shipping");
            }
        }

        set {
            this._OT = value;
        }

    }

}
```

By this, it might not break implementation wherever using parent class

Please find screenshot. It worked

[image]